# ¿Cómo hacer una llamada de este tipo con Python y Bottle?

Tags: python, bottle

Estoy jugando un poco con Python y [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial_app.html). Digamos que tengo mi función en Python para generar un número aleatorio, y pasárselo a la plantilla que le voy a dar a *bottle*:

```
@bottle.route('/')
def web_index():
    val = int(100*random.random()+1) #num aleatorio de 1 a 100
return bottle.template('my_template', val)
```

Con la plantilla conteniendo algo del estilo de

```
Mi valor {{val}}
```

para mostrar el valor generado. Hasta donde yo sé ese valor se inyecta y "se pierde", es decir, aunque yo puedo hacer `bottle.template('my_template', dict(val=val))` no hay forma de recuperar ese diccionario que estoy pasando como contexto a la plantilla al hacer invocaciones GET/POST desde esa plantilla.

Si entonces quisiera añadir dos botones, digamos para incrementar/decrementar el valor generado, mis opciones serían:

1. Hacer una petición al servidor (HTTP request) y que mi código Python gestione la petición. Tendría que enviar en la petición el valor actual `val` para modificarlo, ya que en el lado del servidor no tengo más contexto que lo que pase en la URL.
2. Hacerlo en cliente mediante en JavaScript

Las opciones ni me van ni me vienen (aunque dado que estoy explorando *bottle* me gustaría tirar más por la opción A). Sin embargo, si en lugar de tener un único valor tengo muchos campos estoy obligado a pasarlos todos sólo para poder "refrescar" el valor de uno.

¿Cuál es, entonces, la mejor forma de proceder para implementar este tipo de funcionalidad (modificar via un botón el valor de un campo en un formulario que puede tener muchos campos) teniendo en cuenta que queremos usar el framework *bottle*?

Comment: No entiendo muy bien lo que estás tratando de hacer, el valor que le estás pasando es solo una variable dentro del scope de tu función, si quisieras incrementarla o decrementarla sin usar base de datos, se me ocurre que puedes hacerlo con algún tipo de sesión.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como mencioné en mi comentario, podrías usar [sesiones](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/recipes.html#keeping-track-of-sessions) para que el valor persista cuando lo incrementes o lo decrementes. Para esto, `bottle` recomienda hacer uso de la librería [`beaker`](http://beaker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

### Instalación

```
$ pip install bottle beaker
```

### Ejemplo

Tu vista o controlador:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import bottle
from beaker.middleware import SessionMiddleware


session_opts = {
    'session.type': 'file',
    'session.cookie_expires': 300,
    'session.data_dir': './data',
    'session.auto': True
}
app = SessionMiddleware(bottle.app(), session_opts)


@bottle.route('/', method=['GET', 'POST'])
def web_index():
    # Obtenemos el valor actual de la sesión
    s = bottle.request.environ.get('beaker.session')
    val = s.get('val', 0)
    if 'incrementar' in bottle.request.POST:
        val += 1
    elif 'decrementar' in bottle.request.POST:
        val -= 1
    # Guardamos el valor en la sesión
    s['val'] = val
    s.save()
    return bottle.template('my_template.html', val=val)

bottle.run(app=app, port=8080)
```

El template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Valor actual: {{ val }}</p>
        <form method="POST">
            <input name="incrementar" type="submit" value="Incrementar">
            <input name="decrementar" type="submit" value="Decrementar">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias. Sí esto es más o menos lo que quería. Lo probaré esta tarde cuando pueda sacar un rato. No conocía _Beaker_, y creo que los árboles no me dejaban ver el bosque. Pensaba que tendría que construir mi propio SessionDAO para obtener lo que ya me va a dar _Beaker_. En sesión, nada m impide tener un objeto JSON, con todos los valores de mi formulario, no? Puedo recoger el objeto, actualizar el campo necesario y volver a inyectar el objeto JSON/dict a la plantilla con bottle.

Comment: @Diego asi es, no deberias tener problemas para guardar en la sesión otro tipo de objectos como una lista o diccionario, por ejemplo

Comment: Me ha costado un poquito sacar tiempo para "cacharrear" con esto, pero funciona muy bien. Sólo he tenido que cambiar el nombre de la plantilla a '.tpl' (que es simplemente mi configuración). Ahora voy a adaptarlo en mi código y a jugar un poco con beaker y la sesión. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: @Diego no hay problema, de nada :-)